# Как построить непрерывный график из дискретных данных?

Tags: python, алгоритм, postgresql, любой-язык

Есть массив значений значения абсцисс(начало и конец по времени или по расстоянию) и интеграл (сумма значений, например, объем переданных данных или количество человек) `[(x1,x2,S1),(x3,x4,S2)....]`

[image: график]

Как по нему построить гладкую кривую, такую чтоб площадь под кривой была примерно равна сумме площадей?

Ступенчатый график получил:

```
import heapq
l = [(1,5,10),(3,6,10),(4,5,10)]
heapq.heapify(l)
def agg(data):
    dec = []
    heapq.heapify(dec)
    y=0
    for x1,x2,s in data:
        while dec and dec[0][0] < x1:
            x2, dy = heapq.heappop(dec)
            yield x2,y
            y-=dy
            yield x2,y
        yield x1,y
        dy=s/(x2-x1)
        y+=dy
        yield x1,y
        dec.append((x2,dy))
    while dec:
        x2, dy = heapq.heappop(dec)
        y-=dy
        yield x2, y

for x,y in agg(l):
    print("({:.2f}, {:.2f})".format(x,y))
```

Дальше можно срезать углы, а потом уменьшать количество точек. Но проблема в том что при этом срежутся все пики.

Другой способ придумал - разбить ступеньку на сектора и пересчитать площадь- построить новую ступеньку, а потом резать углы. Вот код с резанными углами.

```
import math
import heapq

def agg2(data, step = 1):
    step = step*2
    def monotonic():
        x=math.floor(data[0][0]/step)*step
        while True:
            yield x
            x+=step
    tail = []
    heapq.heapify(tail)
    for x in monotonic():
        s=0
        while tail and tail[0][0] < (x+step):
            x2,s2 = heapq.heappop(tail)
            s+=s2
        while data and data[0][0] < (x+step):
            x1,x2,s0 = data.pop()
            if (x2-(x+step)) > 0:
                s1=((x+step)-x1)/(x2-(x+step)) * s0
                heapq.heappush(tail, (x2,s0-s1))
            else:
                s1 = s0
            s+=s1

        yield x,x+step,s
        if not (data or tail):
            break


def diff(data):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for x1,x2,s in data:
        dy = s/(x2-x1) - y
        x=x1
        y+=dy/2
        yield x, y
        x=(x2+x1)/2
        y+=dy/2
        yield x, y
        x=x2
        y=s/(x2-x1)/2
    yield x, y


data = [(1,5,10),(3,6,10),(4,5,10), (8,10,10)]
heapq.heapify(data)

for x,y in diff(agg2(data)):
    print("({:.2f}, {:.2f})".format(x,y))
```

Но неужели нет чего-то готового для таких интерполяций?

**Лучше всего реализовать это через какую-то агрегацию на postgresql.**

А пока остановлюсь на делении кубиков на монотонные отсчеты и сглажу колоколом на клиенте...

Comment: Вы понимаете, что таких кривых - бесконечно много? Надо уточнить задачу. Например, можно построить кривулю, у которой вся площадь сосредоточится над S1 - но вы же явно не этого хотите. А чего именно?

Comment: на произвольном отрезке. размеры блоков могут быть больше этого отрезка или меньше.

Comment: То, что вы спрашиваете, более всего похоже на [Kernel Density Estimation](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.13-kernel-density-estimation.html) - как по столбикам гистрограммы построить гладкое мультимодальное распределение. В scipy я пользовался [gaussian_kde](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) чисто для красоты, сгладить гистограмму.

Comment: похоже, но в примерах не вижу входных данных похожих на мои... посмотрю ещё раз. иа так вот генератор гстограмы сделать бы на sql

Answer (score 4):

Замените каждый отрезок на функцию "колокола", и просуммируйте результат.
Можно использовать разные функции "колокола" (производную от любого [сигмоида](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0)).
Например производная логистической функции:

```
#  integral( bell, -inf, +inf ) == 1.
bell = lambda x : math.exp(-x) * (1+ math.exp(-x) )**-2
bell_width = 1/bell(0.)
def bell_summ(x, data):
     y=0.
     for x1,x2,s in data:
          y+= s/(x2-x1) * bell( (x-(x1+x2)/2)/(x2-x1) * bell_width )
     return y

data = [(1,5,10),(3,6,10),(4,5,10)]
interpolated = lambda x : bell_summ(x, data)

for x in range(0., 10., 0.1):
     print("({:.2f}, {:.2f})".format( x , interpolated(x) )
```

Comment: Высокая сложность. Тут для каждой точки суммируются все данные. Надо чтото ближе к линейному..

Comment: (В исходной постановке вопроса, про сложность ничего небыло.) С практической точки зрения, достаточно суммировать только те отрезки, которые лежат не более чем в n раз дальше, чем ширина отрезка. (n- зависит от точности, и выбранной функции колокола). Для Гауссова и логистичского колокола - хвосты падают экспоненциально. Т.е нужно выбрать из базы только отрезки `( (x>x1-(x2-x1)*n) AND (x<x2+(x2-x1)*n) )`.

Comment: да и ширину колоколов подбирать...

Comment: правильно поставленный вопрос это 90% решения ;)

Comment: Единственная логичная ширина колокола - ширина отрезка. Иначе предется завязываться на физическую природу данных.

Comment: ширина там не особо логичная. такие интерполяции хочу построить для разных данных, вот один набор к примеру `"avg" : 3828, "min" : 1, "max" : 598634, "count" : 77377`  (по ширине)

Answer (score 0):

На примере ваших данных сделал гладкое распределение средствами [KDE - Kernel Density Estimation](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.13-kernel-density-estimation.html)

Исходные данные: `data=[(1.0,5.0,10.0),(3.0,6.0,10.0),(4.0,5.0,10.0)]`
Для пересекающихся интервалов я просуммировал значения. Получил вот такую нормализованную гистограмму:
[image: bars.png]

Вот результат сглаживания:
[image: bars_pdf.png]

Скрипт использует matplotlib.pyplot для генерации изображений и сохранения их в файле. На экран ничего не выводит, генерирует три файла:

- `bars.png` - гистограмма,
- `pdf.png` - сглаженная плотность вероятности (probability density function)
- `bars_pdf.png` - гистограмма и плотность вероятности на одном графике

```
import numpy as np

# sample data
data=[(1.0,5.0,10.0),(3.0,6.0,10.0),(4.0,5.0,10.0)]

left=min(x1 for x1,_,_ in data)
right=max(x2 for _,x2,_ in data)

# to make the distributes smoother, resample the original distribution
step=0.1
points=np.arange(left,right+step/2,step)
slices = [(points[i],points[i+1]) for i in range(len(points)-1)]
points = points[:-1] # remove last point

def compute_weights(data, slices):
    for s1,s2 in slices:
        total = 0
        for x1,x2,d in data:
            if s2 <= x1: continue
            if x2 <= s1: continue
            total += d/(x2-x1)
        yield (s1, s2, total)

intervals = list(compute_weights(data, slices))
total_weight=sum(w for _,_,w in data)

# normalize the distribution
weights = np.array(list(w/total_weight for _,_,w in intervals))

# Draw the bars
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(points, weights, step, align='edge')
# save to file rather than display on the screen
plt.savefig('bars.png')

# Approximate the distribution
from scipy import stats

kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(points, weights=weights)
X=np.arange(left-1,right+1,0.1)
Y=kernel(X)

# Erase the plot, draw smoothened distribution
plt.close()
plt.plot(X,Y,'r')
plt.savefig('pdf.png')

# Draw both bar and curve
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(points, weights, step, align='edge')
# red dashed
ax.plot(X,Y,'r--')
plt.savefig('bars_pdf.png')
```

Comment: Давай реальные данные скину?)

Comment: @eri, Жги! pakuula@gmail.com

Comment: @eri, но так то достаточно их подставить в переменную data в четвертой строке ;)